# Using PHP variable in header function

Tags: php

I am trying to incorporate a variable within a PHP header function and it doesn't seem to be working, it shows the actual variable in the address bar or just loads a blank screen. I appreciate your help with this.

The code as follows

```
header('Location: http://'.$soft_url/main');
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? That won't work, because there's a syntax error in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is formatted wrong.

```
header('Location: http://'.$soft_url.'/main');
```

might solve your issue

Comment: Why use single quotes and then go through all the trouble of gluing multiple strings together when double-quotes should do this for you automatically?

Comment: No need, PHP will take longer to concatenate.

Comment: @tadman - I tend to explicitly concatenate things; I find it makes the code a lot easier to read.

Comment: It's a difficult one. The difference between single quotes and double quotes is small, but often single quotes are more efficient (as far as I am aware). As said before explicitly concatenating is easy to read.

Comment: Wrong

Single quotes are more efficient when you're not adding variables in the middle of the string.

Comment: Like I said, it's a difficult one. I don't know for sure which is more efficient in this situation (as I said, as far as I am aware they were more efficient), to be honest, I just corrected his code!

Comment: @andrewsi: any decent code editor can properly colorize php variables, no matter where they are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header('Location: http://' . $soft_url . '/main');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header("Location: http://$soft_url/main");
```